# NSKeyedUnarchiver + UITableViewController not functioning correctly

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nskeyedarchiver

I am attempting to use NSKeyedArchiver to store the state of my UITabBarController.  Inside the tabs are UINavigationControllers which contain UITableViewControllers.

The archiving appears to work without any problem.

When unarchiving I am running into strange problems with my UITableViewControllers.  initWithCoder: is called correctly, and the first thing I am doing inside there is calling [super initWithCoder:]

The tableView appears to be correctly recreated, and has a delegate and dataSource property already set.  If my initWithCoder: does nothing but call super and return self then my table view ends up empty and my delegate methods are not called.  If I hookup the delegate and dataSource properties of self.tableView I see my content correctly, but didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called upon selecting, and in one instance I am unable to scroll until the tableView is reloaded.

If in initWithCoder: I create a new UITableView everything works but I don't believe I should need to do this.

Am I doing something I shouldn't be in attempting this, or am I missing something obvious that I need to add to get things working correctly?

**Update:** setting `self.tableView = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"tableView"]` inside my controller seems to solve the scroll/select problem, but the resulting tableView is always UITableViewStylePlain and still seems like the wrong thing to do as the property is already set.

Answer (score 0):

Your design pattern is certainly unusual.  Normally, you wouldn't try to archive the table view, just the data used to create it.  Then when you need the table view again, you would recreate it from those data, using the same code you used to create it in the first place.

Comment: It's only really archived as side effect of encoding the tab controller as the root object, the basic idea is to have an easy way to store the view stack on for each of the navigation controllers, which all have their own properties / ivars (and in a corner case be quite deep).  The actual data for the table view is being reloaded so I guess creating a new one is an option (that does solve the problems), it just seemed wrong as there was seemingly an object already created.

Comment: Looking at the UITableView class reference, it says it conforms to NSCoding(UIScrollView).  I think this means that only the UIScrollView properties are encoded.  So if you wanted to preserve any properties that are defined at the UITableView level, you would have to encode and decode them yourself.  This should be possible, but unless you have a performance problem recreating everything from scratch, I think that approach is likely to be superior.